In "Знания русского языка", is знания nominative plural or genitive singular?
I guess it is nominative plural, but maybe it could be both?
If this is the title of an article, could I somehow read it as From knowledge of the Russian language (as in legal language) instead of Russian Language Knowledge(s)?
Maybe there is something else I don't know about yet.

If it is a topic of an article (i.e. the title, without any more context), than I'd say it is not grammatically correct. I would say that it should be singular here. "Проверка знания русского языка" is grammatically correct, and it is singular genitive. "У него обширные знания русского языка" is plural nominative, but sounds grammatically incorrect to me.

"Nominative plural" is the phrase in English, not "plural nominative".

Generalization in Russian normally demands using plural.

It can be both depending on the context, so you better give the whole sentence where you have seen it. Just think of the following two examples:

Его знания русского языка весьма обширны.
Нехватка знания русского языка мешает ему говорить грамотно.



I guess it is plural nominative, but maybe it could be both?

Not really*. The use of the plural is weird here, but the plural nominative is the only reading which realistically makes sense.

* One technically possible reading of this phrase in the singular genitive is it being a slogan, a wish, or similar: Хлеба и зрелищ! Чистого неба над головой! Защиты и покровительства! etc., with an implied "I ask for; I wish; I demand" and so on.
If it were this meaning indeed, it would most certainly come with an exclamation mark.
